# yield inside section in Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-8

I am trying to yield a section inside another section which is itself yielded in `master.blade.php`, but it does not work.

#### `master.blade.php`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    welcome to X store
    
    @yield('content')
</body>
</html>
```

##### `shop.blade.php` (This is the view that I have called in the router) `view('shop')`

```html
@extends('master')

@section('content') 
    <h1> Hello ! This is Shop page </h1>
    @yield('products')
@endsection
```

`products-grid.blade.php` => this is the section that i want to yield in Shop view

```html
@extends('shop')

@section('products')
    <h3> product 1 </h3>
    <h3> product 2 </h3>
    <h3> product 3 </h3>
    <h3> product 4 </h3>
@endsection
```

result

```html
welcome to X store
Hello ! This is Shop page
```

Answer (score 1):

In products-grid.blade.php try @parent after @section('products')

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use

@include ('products-grid') instead of @yield('products')

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is the problem that you cannot yield before finishing a section try to call the yield out side of the section